# Android Table Layout on Changing Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablelayout

I am using table layouts dynamically.
The first look of the screen is perfect. 
But soon I go to any other `Fragment` screen (or to previous fragment using previous button, the screen changes in the way that can be viewed in the picture 2.

Has anyone ever faced such an issue?

Note: The column2 which is having the problem is actually a multi line `EditText` with height as  wrap content.

[image: This is the first look of my screen]

[image: This is the second look of my screen]

Comment: please provide your layout file

Comment: Layout file has nothing in it. TableLayout is added dynamically in class file and added to the layout file views.